# Ajax POST request with basic authentication is failing (401 error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post

I'm trying to send a very simple Ajax POST request with basic authentication to a REST API.
With Postman all seems to be OK, but when I do it through my webpage using jQuery, I'm getting a 401 error.

After several other attempts, currently this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://admin:admin@my_rest_api_url',
   data: { "name":"John","surname":"Doe" },
   crossDomain: true
});
```

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: Use Postman for generate the c# code and put it on the question too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: I'd tried that solution but didn't work either. Well, thanks @ErickLangfordXenes for the idea of generating the code from Postman, I didn't know there is this option.

Comment: This is the C# code: ```var client = new RestClient("http://my_rest_api_url");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "57dc5705-5e51-88c4-2518-d790433d464b");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n  \"name\": \"John\",\n  \"surname\": \"Doe\", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);```

(In the place of my_rest_api_url I have the real URL)

Comment: OK, silly from my part, I was trying to do the ajax request from a different domain and apparently this cannot work from a webpage. I'm closing the question.